# How to achieve responsive design for gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have implemented responsive design to my asp.net project. But when I come to grid view control in responsive design, I have faced some difficulties because gridview control is rendering as table in browsers. I am searching some tutorials for grid view responsive design. All are based on jquery. Is there any chance to design gridview with pure css?

Comment: Why not use bootstrap css framework or foundation?

Comment: I am curious how do you do responsive design for a table (i.e. GridView) in general? What is the desired output. I have seen some versions where columns just disappear but it seems so unusable in practice.

Comment: If you are using table `!important` and inline styles will help you.